# Sufficient condition for a quotient to inherit a foliation

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Let $M$ be a manifold, equipped with a (regular) foliation $\mathcal{F}$. Let $R \subset M \times M$ be an equivalence relation.
Godement's theorem states under some conditions, $M/R$ is a smooth manifold.
I'm trying to find sufficient conditions for the foliation $\mathcal{F}$ to induce a foliation on $M/R$.

At the moment, I'm not making any progress. A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only sufficient condition that I can come up with is the following: Suppose we are in the setting of Godement's theorem. Then we can endow the $M/R$ with a smooth structure making $\pi: M \rightarrow M/R$ a smooth submersion.

First, we want this map to be a surjective submersion, and we want the map to have connected fibers. Then, we want a compatibiliity condition between $\pi$ and the foliation $\mathcal{F}$. My current guess would be that $C^{\infty}(M;ker d\pi) \subset \mathcal{F}$, but this seems way too much to ask.